# What is the best Mail server to be used side by side with Apache tomcat?

Tags: email-server, email

what is the best Mail server to be used side by side with Apache tomcat (which host my main webapp) which I configured to run on port 80?  Currently, I have this requirement that I need to setup a mail server under the same server with this address mail.mydomain.com

Comment: Whatever suits you, sir. Please fill in your question to include couple of more things: the operating system you use, are you going to only send mail or do you need to receive it, what kind of mail volume are we talking about, do you need to access that mail via IMAP/POP/webmail ... A blind guess from me would be "If you use Linux or some Unix variant, go ahead with Postfix. For your reading needs use Dovecot (or Cyrus for bigger, complex installations)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any standards-compliant SMTP server should be more than capable of handling a bit of mail.  Also note that you don't necessarily need to run the mail server on the same machine (ie "address") as a web application for the same domain.  MX records are wonderful things.

Comment: Beat to the answer by 4 seconds! Curse you, Dudley Do Right! You and your Nell!

Comment: I was faster than both of you, but just added a humble, shy little comment.

Comment: @Janne Be assertive and aggressive like us! =)

Comment: @WesleyDavid: YARRRRRRRRRRR I will loot your karma!

Answer (score 1):

Asking "What is the best" for anything is going to get you subjective answers (and likely get the question closed). You have to ask yourself if there a compelling reason to run a mail server as a servlet within Tomcat? Likely there is not, unless for some oddball reason the application cannot communicate with service that outside of Tomcat.

If you need an email server, and assuming you're running Linux, I would say to use [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/). It's easier than sendmail and has a large userbase. You can use [a number of Postfix GUI front ends](http://www.debianadmin.com/postfix-mail-server-web-interfacefrontend-or-gui-tools.html) if you want. [Postfix Admin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/postfixadmin/) looks pretty good.

Comment: thanks for the advise with Postfix, I believe subjective answers is quite helpful specially when starting out.